# Проблема с конвертацией string в json android retrofit

Tags: android, клиент-сервер, retrofit, request

У меня есть много вопросов по работе с библиотекой retrofit. С помощью этой библиотеки я пытаюсь создать приложение веб-сервис. Вроде как, я теперь даже не уверен, у меня должно все работать правильно и я должен при послании запроса на сервер, получать адекватный ответ, то есть получать два токена. У меня используется два поля edittext и кнопка для отправки запроса. Уже в процессе разработки было выявлено много проблем на стороне сервера. Но вот у меня возникла проблема которую я вроде как решил но серверу так не кажется. Проблема в том что на сервере ждут обычный json, который я должен получить из информации введенной в edittext. у меня есть интерфейс:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface APIService {
    @Headers("Content-type: application/json")
    @POST("/v1/login")
    Call<Post> auth(@Body Post body);
}
```

как вы можете увидеть что там есть хедер где четко прописано что нужно отправлять только в формате json но вот какой ответ мне шлет сервер:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/OkHttp: --> POST https://мой сервер/v1/login
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Length: 42
    {"login":"Drew","password":"passWORD1234"}
    --> END POST (42-byte body)
D/OkHttp: <-- 400 https://мой сервер/v1/login (343ms)
    Date: Fri, 13 Jul 2018 10:56:06 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
    Content-Length: 51
    P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="NOI ADM DEV COM NAV OUR STP"
    Connection: close
    Content-Type: application/json
D/OkHttp: {"error_code": 6, "message": "invalid_data_format"}
    <-- END HTTP (51-byte body)
```

ему(серверу) я так понял не подходит формат данных который я ему шлю, и он соответственно пишет что инвалид (не я надеюсь)) ). Я уже кинул настройку что-бы все данные из edittext сериализовались но все равно ничего не помогло. Могу дополнить вопрос чем нужно, спрашивайте что нужно то докину.вот то что мне дали с сервера:

```
https://мой сайт /v1/login POST
Can accept id of user or username with password
Params:
{
    "id": int,
    "username": str,
    "password": str
}
```

Если кто заметил где у меня ошибка буду рад если покажете где именно.

Comment: В теории всё правильно - у Вас отправляется json и заголовок `Content-Type: application/json`. Но сервер ругается кодом 400 (Bad Request), то есть он ждал что-то другое -  похоже ему не нравится содержимое json-строки (может имена полей не такие, или ещё чего-то не хватает). Вам бекенд вообще предоставил формат запроса, каким он должен быть? Покажите нам - вопрос скорее решится.

Comment: В Вашем классе `Post` замените `@SerializedName("login")` на `@SerializedName("username")`

Comment: В Вашем интерфейсе для ретрофита класс для реквеста и респонса описан один и тот же. Предполагаю, что они должны отличаться
Call<Post> auth(@Body Post body);

Comment: итак по второму комменту вопрос - неужели сервер ждет переменные?? ну то есть мне раньше казалось мы должны кидать на сервер данные которые принимаются на сервере как переменные, но что-бы от названия что-то зависело то я никогда бы не подумал, по третьему комменту тоже есть вопрос - обязательно-ли задавать реквест и респонс, можно ли задать просто реквест без респонса, ну а сам респонс уже в mainactivity проверять? спасибо за советы кстати, я бы никогда до такого не додумался))

Comment: Сервер ждёт json,  и будет из него доставать значения по известным ему ключам, либо парсить в модель - и как он определит где логин, а где пароль, если они обозваны неизвестными ему именами, а порядок полей в json не гарантирован? `Call<Post>` - класс указанный здесь придёт Вам в `onResponse` в качестве `body`, если Вы не хотите использовать POJO можно указать стандартный `ResponseBody` - это будет "сырой" ответ ни во что не конвертированный.